# How to interpret mysql output in shell script?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

**What I try:**

```
player=tester111

id=$(mysql -h "127.0.0.1" -u "myuser" -ppassword "database" -e \
  "SELECT id FROM login WHERE name='$player';")

echo $id
```

**The following output appears:**

```
id 223
```

How to get ONLY `223` as output?

*I am new to stackoverflow, feel free to comment so I can improve my asking skills.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-N` switch when executing your query. `-N` is for skipping column name and thus you will get only values returned (that is `223` returned) like

```
id=$(mysql -N -h "127.0.0.1" -u "myuser" -ppassword "database" -e \
  "SELECT id FROM login WHERE name='$player';")
```

Comment: Epic! Thx alot :)